# Event Callback on mouse hover in dash, python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have table and a corresponding paragraph:

TABLE

|Metric 1 | Metric 2| Metric 3|...|

PARAGRAPH

A quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog.

Above is certain a paragraph that needs to be changed if the user hover overs the metric1 or metric2 etc.

I have value associated with certain words of the paragraph and I would like those words to be highlighted and their values visible in top of them. Something like this

PARAGRAPH

```
 0.8      -1.2    -0.1        1.1
```

A **quick** **brown** fox **jumped** over a **lazy** dog

Have been looking for hours now... thanks for help!